# Error Dependencies Exists when attempting to Uninstall the Dream House App - Can't Uninstall

Tags: lightning-aura-components, app

Recently I tried uninstalling the Dreamhouse app and I was able to success fully remove most components using the Uninstall button in the Installed Packages page. However there are a few lightning Component dependencies that I can't remove:

1. MortgageCalculator
2. MortageChanged

Instead, I get this error when trying to remove the first Lightning component - MortgageCalculator:

> Referenced by a component instance inside the Lightning page
>   Dreamhouse App Utility Bar : Lightning Page.
>   (I am assumnig the Utility Bar was a child component of the Lightning Dreamhouse app page)

The strange thing is that I have already removed the Lightning App page for Dreamhouse App.

How do I removed the MortgageCalculator component form the Dreamhouse App Utility Utility Bar?

Comment: You need to remove all references to any DreamHouse related metadata.  Remove MortgageCalculator from the utility bar and delete any other referenced. metadata.

Comment: @MertYALTI  Thanks I was abkle to remove those meta data  from the  DH Utility Bar but I think I really screwed up the TP (TRailhead layground)  because what I am now seeing is that I have 3 objects: Property__c, Broker__c and Activity that are in what seems to be an "eternal" relationship and I can get rid of the 2 custom objects of those 3. Recently, I just found a way to successfully remove the Dream House app from a TP by 1) just deactivating all of the Process Builder flows/modules and then 2) uninstalling for full deletion -  not saving the remains of the deleted app for 48 hours.

Answer (score 0):

So hopefully to help prevent this from happening to others when uninstalling Dreamhouse:

I searched for more info on ths topic and I discovered that based on the following link, I should've deactivated the process flows first and the uninstalled Dreamhouse package.  (See **Sawako Sagliano's** answer: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000t2vMQAQ )

Just to test Sawako's steps, I opened up another Trailhead Playground (TP2) and :

1. Installed Dreahouse package in SF.
2. Deactivated the processes in DreamHouse
3. Uninstalled the Dreamhouse package
4. Verify that the Dreamhouse packaged was successfully uninstalled.

It uninstalled cleanly.